# Debezium connectionpool config

Tags: java, quarkus, debezium

I want to configure a connectionpool, because I'm getting a lot of connection retry errors from Debezium after a while:

```
Producer failure: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Database connection failed when reading from copy
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readFromCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1166)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.CopyDualImpl.readFromCopy(CopyDualImpl.java:44)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.receiveNextData(V3PGReplicationStream.java:160)
```

So I digged in the source code and I found out that it provides some configuration for a connectionpool, but I can't get it working properly.

This is what I have currently, and btw Im using Quarkus 2.16.7, Debezium 2.2.1.Final and Posgres 14:

```java
@Startup
public class DebeziumConnectionPoolConfig implements JdbcConnection.ConnectionFactory {

    @Inject
    AgroalDataSource datasource;

    @Override
    public Connection connect(JdbcConfiguration jdbcConfiguration) throws SQLException {    
        return this.datasource.getConnection();       
    }
}
```

And I have the folling configuration in my application.properties:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5435/postgres
quarkus.datasource.username=postgres
quarkus.datasource.password=postgres

# DEBEZIUM
name=my-cdc
database.connection.factory.class=org.acme.dbz.config.DebeziumConnectionPoolConfig
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
database.dbname=postgres
database.hostname=localhost
database.user=postgres
database.password=postgres
database.port=5435
```

And I'm getting connection validation errors during startup:

```
 ERROR [io.deb.con.pos.PostgresConnector] (executor-thread-0) Failed testing connection for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5435/postgres with user 'postgres': org.p
ostgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5435 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:342)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:253)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291)
        at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.lambda$patternBasedFactory$1(JdbcConnection.java:241)
        at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection$ConnectionFactoryDecorator.connect(JdbcConnection.java:127)
        at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.connection(JdbcConnection.java:873)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector.validateConnection(PostgresConnector.java:90)
```

Comment: OK, I've managed to fix the problem. It was a misconfiguration of the connectionpool in Quarkus. But now I'm facing another problem, which I didn't have before I had setup a connectionpool: debezium tries to execute "IDENTIFY_SYSTEM" query, and this doesn't work and it's not recognized as a valid statement. The only way I could make this query work manually is by running "psql "replication=database" -c "IDENTIFY_SYSTEM;", but how do you configure this in debezium then ?

Comment: Another thing I've noticed is that my connectionpool class, is created/initialized many times. I was expecting to be initialized only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally configured a connection pool in the hope that this would solve the connection/restart problems we have with Debezium. But alas, we still have the same issue that Debezium occassionaly after a long run, cannot connect to the database anymore with throwing:

```
Producer failure: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Database connection failed when reading from copy
```

Anyways, for anyone who is interested in the solution, here it is.

Note that Debezium runs different queries to gather information, and 1 of these queries require additional jdbc properties to work. That's why you see a split in the code.

```java
public class DebeziumConnectionPoolConfig implements JdbcConnection.ConnectionFactory {

    @Override
    public Connection connect(JdbcConfiguration config) {       
        Log.infof("Debezium connectionPool initializing...");

        try {
            var replication = config.getString("replication");
            if (isNullOrEmpty(replication)) {
                Log.debugf("Returning Connection from Agroal ConnectionPool");

                return CDI.current().select(AgroalDataSource.class).get().getConnection().unwrap(BaseConnection.class);
            } else {
                // If replication is in the config, then Debezium uses this to perform the following query: IDENTIFY_SYSTEM.
                // To perform this query, a lot of other config properties need to be provided. And these properties are
                // only needed for running this query. If these properties are used as default, then normal queries cannot be performed.
                // That's why agroal is used as the default connectionpool and only during startup when Debezium needs to run IDENTIFY_SYSTEM,
                // a single manual connection is returned.
                Log.debugf("Returning connection from DriverManager");

                var url = "quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url";
                return DriverManager.getConnection(ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue(url, String.class), config.asProperties());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And my application.properties:

```
# AGROAL CONFIG
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5435/postgres
quarkus.datasource.username=postgres
quarkus.datasource.password=postgres

# DEBEZIUM CONFIG
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
database.connection.factory.class=org.acme.dbz.config.DebeziumConnectionPoolConfig
database.dbname=postgres
database.hostname=localhost
database.user=postgres
database.password=postgres
database.port=5435
```